# problem in creating a loop cut

Tags: rendering

i am trying to create a loop cut over the wall with a extended cube. But it is not working.
here is the my file link;
https://pasteall.org/media/9/d/9d0e476691bb2663e54948a09ffcf999.blend
can anyone help?

Comment: you can't create a loop cut through a face that is not a quad as Blender don't know where it is supposed to cut next. Keep a topology with quads

Comment: but how? Can you please explain @moonboots ?

Comment: when you model your object, try to keep quads as much as possible, it will help to keep a topology that will be easy to work and render. Sometimes tris or ngons (more than 4 vertices) are OK, but you won't be able to automatically cut an edge loop through them. You can use the knife tool to cut through an ngon though.

Comment: ok thank you @moonboots

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.